# Youtube embed iframe show black iframe for a moment

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, youtube

I need to embed some videos on my page using YouTube iframe api.

In my code, when an User click a button "Add Video" I need to add an arbitration number of iframes.

For technical reasons (in my real world app code) I need to add this code using `innerHTML` property.

I am aware that changing `innerHTML` causes the black short delay to appear as you can see pressing several time the "Add Video" button in the live example.

- I would like to know if there is way minimize the black short delay without changing the use of  `innerHTML`.

Live demo
https://jsbin.com/kififenequ/edit?html,output

```
(function (window) {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', event => {
        let html = '<iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/jm0lzLHxauY?rel=0&amp;controls=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';

        let fragmentFromString = function (strHTML) {
            return document.createRange().createContextualFragment(strHTML);
        }

        let elmVideos = document.getElementById('videos');
        let elmBtnInsert = document.getElementById('btn-insert');

        elmBtnInsert.addEventListener('click', event => {
            elmVideos.innerHTML += html; // I CANNOT CHANGE THIS
        });
    });
})(window);
```

Answer (score 1):

`innerHTML` is not the cause for the black flickering. You can even see it when you open the iframe url in your browser directly: https://www.youtube.com/embed/jm0lzLHxauY?rel=0&controls=0

The preview image just needs some time to load, why are you so bothered about that? What you could do is add the iframe invisible, wait for the load event of the iframe, then show it. But I think nothing happening is even worse then a bit of black flickering. (Also, there's no guarantee that this would work, depending on the way the YouTube player is loading the image, I didn't look into that)